# Cómo funciona este código?

Tags: javascript

Holaa, estaba tratando de resolver un ej en JavaScript donde tenía que hacer una función que muestre el número más grande en un array dado, y encontré este código y la verdad que no entiendo en absoluto cómo funciona, y me confunde bastante que en el for, i empiece valiendo 1 ya que los índices de los elementos arrancan desde 0. Aquí el código:

```
function largest(arr) {  

    let max = arr[0]; 

    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) 
            max = arr[i]; 
    } 
    return max; 
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Si te fijaste detenidamente, lo pimero que hace es buscar la posición cero y guardar en `max`. El `for` empieza en uno, porque no tiene sentido empezar a comparar el valor de `max` consigo mismo.

Comment: Y pero si yo le pasó un array tipo [300, 1, 2 , 3], como puede chequear el 300 cuyo índice es 0, si i empieza desde 1. No comprendo bien que papel juega el Max..

Comment: En la variable `max` se guarda el número más grande. Se inicializa con el valor en la posición cero. Luego se procede a comparar con el resto.

Comment: en palabras mas simples, toma el primer valor como max y lo va comparando uno a uno con los demás hasta encontrar un valor mas alto y reemplazar max por dicho valor luego continua comparando hasta que al final te queda que max es el valor mas alto

Comment: @XavierVergara respondiendo a tu comentario,  aquí max es 300 let max = arr[0];  luego este 300 se va comparar con el valor 1 ya que no tiene sentido que lo compare con el mismo y suponiendo que 300 es el mas alto nunca se remplazara ese valor y 300 terminara siendo max

Comment: Xavier, si te confunde, entonces, recomiendo que como ejercicio escribas **un algoritmo para encontrar el número más alto de un array**. Por algún lugar tienes que empezar, no? Por el primero. El primero es `arr[0]` y lo comparamos con el siguiente, `arr[1]` y así sucesivamente.

Comment: @Arriel Si claro! Yo lo resolví de otra manera, pero he visto este método en varios lugares y no lograba comprenderlo, por suerte lo estoy entendiendo ahora, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente hace lo siguiente

1. crea una variable MAX y le asigna el primer elemento de tu arreglo
2. mientras i=1...longitud del array itera y va preguntando

   2.1) si MAX > elemento en la posicion i
   Actualiza el MAX
3. retorna el MAX